# Calculate Column Percentage sas

Tags: sas, percentage

I have the following dataset:

```
Date        Occupation      Tota_Employed
1/1/2005      Teacher         45
1/1/2005      Economist       76
1/1/2005      Artist          14
2/1/2005      Doctor          26
2/1/2005      Economist       14
2/1/2005      Mathematician   10

and so on until November 2014
```

What I am trying to do is to calculate a column of percentage of employed by occupation such that my data will look like this:

```
Date        Occupation      Tota_Employed   Percent_Emp_by_Occupation
1/1/2005      Teacher         45               33.33
1/1/2005      Economist       76               56.29
1/1/2005      Artist          14               10.37
2/1/2005      Doctor          26               52.00
2/1/2005      Economist       14               28.00
2/1/2005      Mathematician   10               20.00
```

where the percent_emp_by_occupation is calculated by dividing total_employed by each date (month&year) by total sum for each occupation to get the percentage:

Example for Teacher: (45/135)*100, where 135 is the sum of 45+76+14

I know I can get a table via proc tabulate, but was wondering if there is anyway of getting it through another procedure, specially since I wanted this as a separate dataset.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract month and year from the date and create a key:

```
data ds;
set ds;
month=month(date);
year=year(date);
key=catx("_",month,year);
run;
```

Roll up the total at month level:

```
Proc sql;
create table month_total as
select key,sum(total_employed) as monthly_total
from ds
group by key;
quit;
```

Update the original data with the monthly total:

```
Proc sql;
create table ds as
select a.*,b.monthly_total
from ds as a left join month_total as b
on a.key=b.key;
quit;
```

This would lead to the following data set:

Date    Occupation  Tota_Employed   monthly_total
1/1/2005    Teacher 45  135
1/1/2005    Economist   76  135
1/1/2005    Artist  14  135

Finally calculate the percentage as:

```
data ds;
set ds;
percentage=total_employed/monthly_total;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Nirvik. My train of thought was the exact same, unfortunately I am not good with SQL at all. I wonder if this can also be done without Proc sql. I assume first.variable and last.variable can somehow be used, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
proc sql;
create table occ2 as 
select
    occ.*,
    total_employed/employed_by_date as percentage_employed_by_date format=percent7.1
from 
    occ     a
    join
    (select 
        date,
        sum(total_employed) as employed_by_date
    from occ
    group by date)  b
        on
        a.date = b.date
;
quit;
```

Produces a table like so:

[image]

One last thought:  you can create all of the totals you desire for this calculation in one pass of the data. I looked at a prior question you asked about this data and assumed that you used `proc means` to summarize your initial data by date and occupation. You can calculate the totals by date as well in the same procedure. I don't have your data, so I'll illustrate the concept with sashelp.class data set that comes with every SAS installation.

In this example, I want to get the total number of students by sex and age, but I also want to get the total students by sex because I will calculate the percentage of students by sex later. Here's how to summarize the data and get counts for 2 different levels of summary.

```
proc summary data=sashelp.class;
class sex age;
types sex sex*age;
var height;
output out=summary (drop=_freq_) n=count;
run;
```

The `types` statement identifies the levels of summary of my class variables. In this case, I want counts of just sex, as well as the counts of sex by age. Here's what the output looks like.

[image]

The `_TYPE_` variable identifies the level of summary. The total count of sex is `_TYPE_=2` while the count of sex by age is `_TYPE_=3`.

Then a simple SQL query to calculate the percentages within sex.

```
proc sql;
create table summary2 as
select
    a.sex,
    a.age,
    a.count,
    a.count/b.count as percent_of_sex format=percent7.1
from
    summary (where=(_type_=3))  a  /* sex * age  */
    join
    summary (where=(_type_=2))  b  /* sex  */
        on
        a.sex = b.sex
;
quit;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to look back at the questions you have asked in the last few days about this same data and study those answers. Your answer is there.

While you are reviewing those answers, take time to thank them and give someone a check for helping you out.

Comment: I did read through the answers carefully, but it wasn't helpful with what i was trying to do. Thanks anyway.